# orderby DESC not sort completely true

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by

I want to show sent kits that sent to the users, I want to sort them based on the date, I wrote a code in this form:

```php
$kit_final_ids=Kitstatus::query()
  ->whereIn('kitstatuslist_id',[10,13])
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
  ->pluck('kit_id')->toArray();

$kits=Kit::query()
  ->whereIn('id',$kit_final_ids)
  ->whereIn('kitstatuslist_id',[10,13])
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);

return view('admin.sendingfinalreporttocustomer.allsentfinalkits',compact('kits'));
```

and this is my blade:

```html
<td style="text-align: right!important;font-size: 10px" >
<p>
  {{\App\Models\Kitstatus::query()->where('kit_id',$kit['id'])->where('kitstatuslist_id',13)->first()?\Morilog\Jalali\Jalalian::fromCarbon(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Date::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',\App\Models\Kitstatus::query()->where('kit_id',$kit['id'])->where('kitstatuslist_id',13)->first()->created_at))->format('Y-m-d'):'نامشخص'}}
</p>
</td>


<td style="text-align: right!important;font-size: 10px" >
<p>
  {{\App\Models\Kitstatus::query()->where('kit_id',$kit['id'])->where('kitstatuslist_id',10)->first()?\Morilog\Jalali\Jalalian::fromCarbon(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Date::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',\App\Models\Kitstatus::query()->where('kit_id',$kit['id'])->where('kitstatuslist_id',10)->first()->created_at))->format('Y-m-d'):'نامشخص'}}
</p>
</td>
```

this is my code, but the problem that I have:
first when see the results think is working correctly, but when go to the other pages one by one, see that some part of results in some pages are not sorted correctly, for example in my result in page 5-7 has some unsorted result